# c++filt does not demangle typeid name

Tags: c++, typeid, typeinfo, demangler, c++filt

I am running a code on GCC *C++* compiler, to output the type_info::name:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

class shape {
   protected:
   int color;
   public:
   virtual void draw() = 0;
   };


class Circle: public shape {
   protected:
   int color;
   public:
   Circle(int a = 0): color(a) {};
   void draw();
   };

   void Circle::draw() {
   cout<<"color: "<<color<<'\n';
   }

class triangle: public shape {
   protected:
   int color;
   public:
   triangle(int a = 0): color(a) {};
   void draw();
   };

   void triangle::draw() {
   cout<<"color: "<<color<<'\n';
   }

int main() {
   Circle* a;
   triangle* b;
   cout<<typeid(a).name()<<'\n';
   cout<<typeid(b).name()<<'\n';
   }
```

but I get the following results:

```
P6Circle
P8triangle
```

and on demangling,

```
./shape | c++filt
```

I get the same output as earlier. Any other solution?

Comment: [Name mangling](http://refspecs.linux-foundation.org/cxxabi-1.83.html#mangling) for types is not that complicated, and surely not in that case... I don't know what the answer to your question is, but a workaround is reading the type yourself. `P` pointer to `6Circle` Circle object (the 6 is the length of the name)... `P` pointer to `8triangle` triangle (8 characters).

Comment: Hmm, that is simple. Thanks but just wanted to know if there is a cleaner way of getting the same

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to use `c++filt -t` for types so the following should work:

```
./shape | c++filt -t
```

the [man page for c++filt](http://linux.die.net/man/1/c++filt) says the following for `-t`:

> Attempt to demangle types as well as function names.  This is disabled by default since mangled types are normally only used internally in the compiler, and they can be confused with non-mangled names.  For example, a function called "a" treated as a mangled type name would be demangled to "signed char".

Answer (score 2):

Which version of GCC (and its corresponding *libstdc++*) are you using?

With GCC 4.8, I have

```
static inline std::string 
 demangled_type_info_name(const std::type_info&ti)
{
  int status = 0;
  return abi::__cxa_demangle(ti.name(),0,0,&status);
}
```

and then I can use

```
std::cout << demangled_type_info_name(typeid(*ptr)) << std::endl;
```

where `ptr` points to some object with an [RTTI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information) (i.e. with some virtual methods, notably a virtual destructor).

Comment: Then you should upgrade to GCC 4.8.1 because `typeid` is better implemented there.

Comment: Congratulations, you've just induced hundreds of people to add memory leaks into their apps. You must deallocate the buffer returned by `abi::__cxa_dmangle` after creating the return string.